# Object array loaded twice instead of once, resulting in disorientation of graph

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, csv

I have been trying to load csv files to plot a chart. Here is the code sample used to sort the array and plot the chart.

```
var data = [];
       console.log("here");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(csvData) {

csvData.forEach(function (d,i) {
    data[i] = {
      first: +d.first, 
      second: +d.second,
      text: d.text
    } 
});
console.log(data);

var tmp = data;
tmp.forEach(function(d) { data.push(d); });

var sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b) { 
return a.text > b.text ; 
});


console.log(data);


    var text = [];

 d3.csv("text.csv", function(csvData) {

csvData.forEach(function (d,i) {
    datam[i] = {
      first: +d.textlist
    } 
});
console.log(text);
```

And Here is the link for the complete chart http://plnkr.co/edit/5CeSy2p69TugY3aICc3j?p=preview. The problem with this code is that the object array gets loaded twice i.e. data.csv is loaded twice object array 0, object array 1 hold same values and 2,3 same values. How to overcome this problem and load the csv files ? I want a plot like this

[image]

But I get a plot like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is probably here:

```
var tmp = data;
tmp.forEach(function(d) { data.push(d); });
```

When declaring `tmp`, you are creating a *reference* to `data`, **not** copying it. Therefore, you're essentially duplicating your data, because `tmp` and `data` are the same array.

Instead, you will need to define `tmp` as a new array, like so:

```
var tmp = [];
tmp.forEach(function(d) { data.push(d); });
```

Comment: Jim O'Brien - How to push the data without duplicating ?

Comment: use var tmp = []; to create an empty array

Comment: bilal - The data is getting loaded once now, but same result with the graph plot, no change in the output

Comment: Is it ok to sort like this var sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b) { 
return a.text > b.text ; 
});
after assigning var tmp = []; ?

Comment: Yes - `tmp` and `data` are different variables.